# Accessibility Skip Nav - Skip to Content (Issue in Safari)

Tags: html, css, safari, accessibility

For accessibility I built a skip nav. It's a basic anchor:

```
 <div class="skip-nav">
   <a href="#content">Skip to content</a>
 </div>
```

Linked to the content:

```
<section id="content">
  <h1>Accessibility Skip Nav Demo</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
</section>
```

Pressing tab will reveal the "Skip to content" button based on focus.
My CSS:

```
.skip-nav a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  left: 10px;
  top: 35px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.skip-nav a:focus,
.skip-nav a:active {
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: auto;   
}
```

It works fine in all browsers except in Safari. In Safari trying to **click with the mouse** doesn't work. Here is the jsfiddle (please view in Safari to see the issue): https://jsfiddle.net/461huu5g/

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the clip css for each browser it's look like your firefox and chrome support it but safari does not so:

```css
-webkit-clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
```

try it: 
https://jsfiddle.net/461huu5g/1/

Comment: I don't think -webkit applies for the clip property. But I still tried it and still buggy...

Comment: `clip` predated the `-webkit-` prefix, and according to MDN was supported in Safari 1. It is however deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be related to the use of the `auto` keyword to reset the `clip` property. If you replace `clip: auto;` with `clip: initial;` it will work in Safari. So if you wish to support browser that do not support `initial`, you will probably want both:

```
clip: auto;
clip: initial;
```

And `initial` will override `auto` in browsers that support `initial`.

On a side note, [`clip` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip), in favor of [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), so you may want to consider similar solutions which do not depend on the `clip` property, such as the popular `position: fixed` off-screen with negative positioning.

Comment: I tried replacing clip: auto; with clip: initial; but still an issue. But since clip is deprecated I'll try the clip-path route.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was I didn't have complete coverage. What worked was accounting for **hover**. So my updated css:

```
.skip-nav a:focus,
.skip-nav a:active,
.skip-nav a:hover
{
  position: absolute;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: auto;   
}
```

**HOWEVER**

As Alexander mentioned the **clip** property is deprecated and therefore might break in the future.

**SO A BETTER WAY (USING POSITIONING)**

```
.skip-nav a {
  display: block;
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px); DEPRECATED*/
  left: -1000px;
  top: -1000px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #fff;
}

.skip-nav a:focus,
.skip-nav a:active,
.skip-nav a:hover {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 35px;
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  /*clip: auto; DEPRECATED*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you are helping accessibility by focusing only on screen readers and keyboard users.

If you want to provide a "skip link", then make it visible for everyone and not only on focus, like people with disabilities not using a keyboard (touchscreen, eye tracking devices, voice controlled navigation).