# anchor with href not taking focus in Safari even with all accessibility/keyboard settings enabled

Tags: html, css, safari, accessibility, anchor

I am creating a skip link, but the anchor tag is not taking focus in Safari (works in Chrome). I've enabled all accessibility settings as I've read in other posts:

1. Safari --> Preferences --> Advanced —> checked the box that says “Press Tab to Highlight Each Item on a Webpage”
2. Mac System Preferences --> Keyboard --> Shortcuts --> and then clicked “All Controls” at the bottom

I've also tried adding the :hover pseudoclass in addition to the :focus one as suggested here: [Accessibility Skip Nav - Skip to Content (Issue in Safari)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519744/accessibility-skip-nav-skip-to-content-issue-in-safari)

Tabbing through the content does not make the skip link appear in Safari even with those changes. It works consistently in Chrome. Here is also a codepen with the issue: 
https://codepen.io/a-gheorghe-the-vuer/pen/vVJmZw

```css
.card {
  background-color: yellow;
  left: -1000px;
  top: -1000px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: .1rem solid red;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem 1rem 0 black;
  padding: 3.6rem;
}

.anchor-skip:focus .card {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: .1rem solid red;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem 1rem 0 black;
  padding: 3.6rem;
  display: block;
}

.anchor-skip:hover .card {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: .1rem solid red;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem 1rem 0 black;
  padding: 3.6rem;
  display: block;
}

.anchor-skip:active .card {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: .1rem solid red;
  border-radius: .4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 .2rem 1rem 0 black;
  padding: 3.6rem;
  display: block;
}

.button {
  z-index: 1
}

.check {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
```

```html
        <a
        class="anchor-skip"
        tabindex="0"
        href="#main"
      >
        <div class="card" tabindex="-1">
          <div class="button">
            <span> Skip to main content</span>   
          </div>
        </div>                
      </a>
      <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>
      <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>       <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>       <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>       <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>
      <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>
      <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>       <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>       <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>       <div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div><div> hi </div>    
      <div id="main" class="check"> hello </div>
 <div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: i don't have a mac to test this but see if https://webaim.org/ works.  from the address bar, the first focusable element is the skip link, which is hidden until you tab to it.  does that site work on your mac?

Comment: thanks slugolicious - the skip link on that page does work in Safari for me. I see that the a tag is wrapped in a div and the a tag itself is styled. In my case. I want the a tag to contain several other divs / premade components that all appear/disappear with the skip link.

My question of why my a tag not taking focus still stands - it seems like it needs to be wrapped in a div. Why is that?

Comment: perhaps the timing of unhiding things on safari, i'm not sure.  if it works in other browsers, and the webaim.org site works, then there must be something in your code that is different that is not working.  i would recommend trying to do it the same way webaim does it and see if you can get further that way.  finding out the "why" can come later, and might require asking apple directly

Answer (score 9):

There are a few things going on. The first one is that by default, Safari doesn't use tab navigation. The user has to go into Safari's setting and check the box to turn on tabbed navigation. It's stupid.

The other issue is your markup. Safari doesn't like empty links. Even though you have a div inside the anchor tag, Safari doesn't recognize this as a valid link and therefore ignores it. To correct this issue you'll need to simplify your markup to something like this:

```
<a class="sr-only sr-only-focusable" href="#main">Skip to main content</a>
```

Also, by using semantically correct markup, your link will not need a tabindex. When using the "tab" key to navigate, when the link is in focus, set the display parameter to "block" to make it visible.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

For Skip to main content link:

- Provide a visually hidden link to the anchor
- When anchor receives focus, display the same link
- when user hit the same link then move focus to the target element using javascript focus() function.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML and CSS were not valid, After correcting

[Code pen working code](https://codepen.io/abhishek2kr/pen/ZEjGWYE?editors=1100)

```css
.card {
  background-color: yellow;
  left: -1000px;
  top: -1000px;
  height: 1px;
  width: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.1rem solid red;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1rem 0 black;
  padding: 3.6rem;
}

.holder:focus .card {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 0.1rem solid red;
  border-radius: 0.4rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0.2rem 1rem 0 black;
  padding: 3.6rem;
  display: block;
}

.button {
  z-index: 1;
} /*Here ) was used*/

.check {
  height: 30px;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div tabindex="0" class="holder">
  <a class="anchor-skip" tabIndex="0" href="#main">
    <div class="card" tabindex="-1">
      <div class="button">
        <span> Skip to main content</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div> hi </div>
<div id="main" class="check"> hello </div>
```